# Why does = NULL not work in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, null

I recently realized that we need to use a special syntax `IS NULL` to compare a literal to NULL.

Why does `= NULL` not work here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at [PSOUG's notes on NULL](http://psoug.org/reference/null.html).  As Fabricio Araujo hinted, NULL is not really a value like the number 4 or string 'bacon strips'.  In fact, NULL is [untyped](http://orafaq.com/wiki/NULL) in the SQL language, which is why you cannot validly use it in an equality comparison.  You need the special `IS [NOT] NULL` syntax to check if a value is NULL or not.

Comment: @Nick - I think the orafaq link is misleading when it states that `null` is "untyped". Consider the different result types in the following: `select decode('A','B',to_char(null),'A','1') from dual;` and 
`select decode('A','B',to_number(null),'A','1') from dual;`

Comment: @Jack - How is it misleading?  According to the [reference page for DECODE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm): "Oracle automatically converts the return value to the same datatype as the first result. If the first result has the datatype CHAR or if the first result is null, then Oracle converts the return value to the datatype VARCHAR2."  So in your example, the first 1 is returned as a VARCHAR2 and the second 1 is returned as a NUMBER to match how you casted the NULL.  The NULL itself is still untyped.

Comment: @Jack - Actually, taking a cursory look at [this posting of the SQL-92 standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt), section 4.1 states: "A null value is an implementation-dependent special value that is distinct from all non-null values of the associated data type. There is effectively only one null value and that value is a member of every SQL data type." I would say "untyped" is a good summary of "is a member of every data type". :)

Comment: @Nick - but `to_number(null)` *is still `null`* (`select * from dual where to_number(null) is null;`), it is just a 'typed' `null`.

Comment: @Jack - That's right.  You've casted the original, "untyped" NULL to a "typed" NULL.  The [orafaq link](http://orafaq.com/wiki/NULL) is still correct to say that NULL (which to me implies a "pure" NULL) is untyped, but perhaps they should add that it can be explicitly cast as a specific type.  I wonder if the only impact casting a NULL can have is on functions like DECODE that derive the data type of their output from one of the inputs.

Comment: @Nick - it can affect `union`s too

Comment: @Jack - Oh neat, that's right. [`INTERSECT` and `MINUS`, too](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm).

Comment: @Nick - I decided to post this [as a question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/4412/1396) in it's own right

Answer (score 5):

In SQL Server, we have an connection setting to get `=NULL` to behave equally to `IS NULL`. But in latest versions is not recommended anymore - it's even marked as deprecated.

The recommended is the SQL Standard way - the `IS [NOT] NULL` operator.

(And I will not start an war whether 'NULL is a value or a status' here)... hehehe

Answer (score 2):

Oracle treats NULL as an unknown value.  Ask yourself if this equality works.

```
(unknown amount in George's wallet) = (unknown amount in Harry's wallet)
```

or otherwise stated

```
NULL = NULL
```

The answer is clearly maybe, which is neither true nor false.

---

I will add a little clarification to NULL as I have seen it used:

While NULL really means "not set", in the context of this question I believe the above statement is correct.

There are a number of reasons for a column to have a NULL value:

- The column is not appropriate to the sub-type or state of the row.  (It is known we shouldn't have a value.  In this case, we shouldn't be comparing the value of the column to another value.  Testing for IS NULL may be useful.)
- The value is not available or hasn't been recorded in the column.  (The value exists but for some reason isn't known by the database.  In these cases NULL is equivalent to unknown by the database.)

In some contexts, NULL may be handled in ways that might be considered incorrect, including:

- NULL values may be replaced with a default value.  An unset NOT NULL number is likely to have the value 0.  (This does not necessarily mean the value is known to be 0.)
- An empty string may be converted to NULL or vice versa.  (The value may be known, as empty.)

Comment: Oracle does not treat null as meaning that a value is unknown. Don't confuse the logical truth-value UNKNOWN with the missing value marker NULL - they are different things.

Comment: @Bill - Oracle, and as far as I know all other RDBMS's treat `null` differently according to the context.

Comment: @dportas - `unknown` is not used at all in Oracle (unlike postgres for example)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than justify the `is null` syntax I think it is better to point out that there are no good general rules-of-thumb when dealing with `null`s and the syntax used to handle them. For example:

1. updating a value uses syntax like `set val = null` rather than something like `set val to null` which might mirror the `is null` syntax better
2. it is almost always a mistake when dealing with `null` to say: "nulls behave like so-and-so here, *so they should behave like such-and-such here*

[Here](http://thoughts.davisjeff.com/2009/08/02/what-is-the-deal-with-nulls/) is an excellent essay on the subject from a postgres perspective. Briefly summed up by saying nulls are treated differently depending on the context and don't make the mistake of making any assumptions about them.