# Does NULL have a type?

Tags: datatypes, null

Various sources (eg [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Data_typing), [PSOUG](http://psoug.org/reference/null.html)) state that Oracle's `null` does not have a type. Is this true?

What about other RDBMSs?

Answer (score 8):

Oracle:

The `null` literal does not have a type, but

1. `null` can be cast to any type, and this may be necessary when

   - calling overloaded procedures or functions
   - controlling the return type of the `decode` function, eg:

     ```
     select decode('A','B',to_char(null),'A','1') from dual;
     DECODE('A','B',TO_CHAR(NULL),'A','1')
     -------------------------------------
     1

     select decode('A','B',to_number(null),'A','1') from dual;
     DECODE('A','B',TO_NUMBER(NULL),'A','1')
     --------------------------------------- 
                                           1
     ```
   - controlling column types of set operators like `union` when the first query block includes a `null`
2. `null` values stored in the database *always* have a type:

   ```
   create table t(n integer, s varchar(10));
   insert into t values(null, null);

   select decode('A','B',n,'A','1') from t; 
   DECODE('A','B',N,'A','1')
   -------------------------
                           1

   select decode('A','B',s,'A','1') from t;
   DECODE('A','B',S,'A','1')
   -------------------------
   1
   ```

Comment: +1 For curiosity let's try Select NULL what_type_is_this from DUAL; Of course this no practical useful example and I didn't try it yet, I have learned to use casts in such cases.

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server, int

```
SELECT NULL AS foo INTO dbo.bar
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'bar'
DROP TABLE dbo.bar
```

MySQL, binary(0)

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.foo (select NULL AS bar);
EXPLAIN mydb.foo;
DROP TABLE mydb.foo;
```

Comment: +1 that's very interesting - I assumed that would throw an error like it does on Oracle

Comment: Interesting find. However, this shows that those DB engines default to a datatype when creating tables in that way, not necessarily that NULL has a type in those engines. For example, [this error](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/06/27/sql-server-puzzle-involving-null-resolve-error-operand-data-type-void-type-is-invalid-for-sum-operator/) suggests that SQL Server does indeed treat NULL as untyped.

Comment: @Nick `select isnumeric(null)` = 0... interesting

Answer (score 6):

Oracle it is in some sense some **string** type.

Thats what ADO Reader tells me. here is a Powershell Script:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data.OracleClient") 
$ConnectionString = "Data Source=myTNS;User ID=myUSER;Password=myPassword" 
$conn=new-object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection 
$conn.ConnectionString=$ConnectionString 
$conn.Open() 
$sql = "Select NULL xx from DUAL"
$cmd=new-object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand($sql,$conn)

$r = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

$r.GetSchemaTable() | % { $_
}
```

That gives

```
ColumnName               : XX
ColumnOrdinal            : 0
ColumnSize               : 0
NumericPrecision         : 0
NumericScale             : 0
DataType                 : System.String
ProviderType             : 22
IsLong                   : False
AllowDBNull              : True
IsAliased                : 
IsExpression             : 
IsKey                    : 
IsUnique                 : 
BaseSchemaName           : 
BaseTableName            : 
BaseColumnName           : 
ProviderSpecificDataType : System.Data.OracleClient.OracleString
```

Note the line

ProviderSpecificDataType : **System.Data.OracleClient.OracleString**

Answer (score 3):

postgres:

```
create table foo as select null as bar;
WARNING:  column "bar" has type "unknown"
DETAIL:  Proceeding with relation creation anyway.

postgres=> \d foo

 Column |  Type   | Modifiers
--------+---------+-----------
 bar    | unknown |
```